# SQL Calculate Durations and group them by day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of Signals name of columns are id,signalname,starttime,endtime.

For example:

```
+---------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Name    | DDSEventId                           | StartTime                   | EndTime                      |
+---------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| Start   | 5C365D11-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2013-03-01 02:58:39.0000000 | 2013-03-01  03:58:00.0000000 |
| AnyName | 5C365D12-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2013-03-01 02:59:00.0000000 | 2013-03-01  03:09:00.0000000 |
| AnyName | 5C365D13-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2013-03-01 03:58:39.0000000 | 2013-03-01  04:28:39.0000000 |
| Start   | 5C365D99-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2013-03-01 09:00:00.0000000 | 2013-03-01  09:10:00.0000000 |
| AnyNAme | 77211888-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2013-03-01 13:27:25.0000000 | 2013-03-01 18:00:31.0000000  |
| Start   | 77211815-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A | 2000-01-02 04:27:25.0000000 | 2014-03-02 08:00:31.0000000  |
| AnyName | 43C94D44-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47 | 2013-03-02 09:00:01.0000000 | 2013-03-02 09:59:08.0000000  |
| Start   | 43C94DB2-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47 | 2013-03-02 16:00:01.0000000 | 2013-03-02 17:59:08.0000000  |
| AnyName | 43C94DB3-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47 | 2013-03-02 18:00:01.0000000 | 2013-03-02 18:20:00.0000000  |
| AnyName | 43C94DB6-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47 | 2013-03-02 20:00:01.0000000 | 2013-03-02 23:00:00.0000000  |
+---------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Start= signal which represents the starting point.
AnyName= any random signal.
Query: I want to find total duration in hours machine was ON for each day . and the formula we can use in my case is . (AnyName before Start(Endtime))-Start(StartTime)=duration. and then summing duration for and group by days.

Comment: Not sure I understand your formula, could you pls show the expected output?

Comment: Yes wait a mind i will post the expected output

Comment: Please be more specific - choose one of your DDSEventId's in your sample data-set and give us your expected results so we can work out how your calculation should work

Comment: This isn't a question it's a job. There are other parts of SO for this, have you made any attempt at all ?

Comment: Date         Duration
01/03/13 11:00:31 
02/03/13 12:26:32
EXPLANATION

11:00:31 = 5C365D13-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A(EndTime)-5C365D11-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A(StartTime)+ 77211888-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A(EndTime)-5C365D99-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A(StartTime)

12:26:32= 43C94D44-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47(EndTime)-77211815-B76B-11E3-BF3B-005056B0298A(StartTime)+ 43C94DB6-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47(EndTime)-43C94DB2-84C1-440B-8291-A17400005B47 (StartTime)